# Get all the current Session Variables that being with a certain string

Tags: php, jquery, json

All,
I've created a whole bunch of session variables based on an id. So for example I can have the following variables:

```
$_SESSION['test_variable_1'];
$_SESSION['test_variable_2'];
$_SESSION['test_variable_3'];
```

I'd like to read all of these with PHP and basically return a JSON array of the id at the end of the variable. So I'd like 1, 2 and 3 returned in this example. The session variables I wnat to look at will always start with test_variable_ and followed by the ID I want to obtain. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the better idea would've been to just create a sub-array within the session superglobal, so that you could use `$_SESSION['test_variable'][1]` and the like, you can use something like [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to scan for these keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION);
$matches = preg_grep('/^test_variable_\d+$/', $keys);

foreach($matches as $key) {
   $digit = substr($key, 13); // extract the digit.
   echo $_SESSION[$key];
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, how would I go about setting those variables? Does this work if the ids are of different sizes like 1 and then another one is 34882?

Comment: the \d+ portion looks for ANY digits, so it'd match 1 and 34882 without any trouble. But it won't match `test_variable_` with no digits at all - probably a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ids = array();

foreach($_SESSION as $var => $value) {
  if (strpos($var, 'test_variable_') === 0) {
    $ids[] = str_replace('test_variable_', '', $var);
  }
}
```